# How to deploy .net core 2.1.0 app to docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1.0 application. The database driving the application is Postgres.

I wish to deploy the application and its database as containers. One container housing the application and another the Postgres database.

I searched a lot, but could not find a step by step guide on how to achieve this.

Locally, my application is building fine. In Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.3) I then right-clicked the project file and clicked on Add Docker support. This gave me the following Docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 51986
EXPOSE 44360

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY Phoneden.Web/Phoneden.Web.csproj Phoneden.Web/
COPY Phoneden.DataAccess/Phoneden.DataAccess.csproj Phoneden.DataAccess/
COPY Phoneden.Entities/Phoneden.Entities.csproj Phoneden.Entities/
COPY Phoneden.Services/Phoneden.Services.csproj Phoneden.Services/
COPY Phoneden.ViewModels/Phoneden.ViewModels.csproj Phoneden.ViewModels/
RUN dotnet restore Phoneden.Web/Phoneden.Web.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Phoneden.Web
RUN dotnet build Phoneden.Web.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish Phoneden.Web.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Phoneden.Web.dll"]
```

This also gave me a `docker-compose.yml` file. Inside that, I have put the following:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  phoneden.web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Phoneden.Web/Dockerfile
    environment:
      PaginationSettings: 10
      DefaultConnection: Server=postgres-db;Database=phoneden;Username=postgres;Password=admin;Port=5432;
    container_name: phoneden-web
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:10.4
    restart: always
    ports:
       - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
    container_name: postgres-db
```

**UPDATE**

Using [this program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) I was able to discover that port 5432 was already in use by a local install of Postgres. I changed the ports on `db:` in my `docker-compose.yml` file to be `5434:5434` and now the Postgres Db seems to run fine. However, the asp.net core app now fails and I get this.

[image]

Comment: Go to the command line and `cd` into the folder containing the `docker-compose.yml`. Then run `docker-compose up` and you should see more details.

Comment: added update, thank you.

Comment: Please make sure Port 5432 is not used by another program or another instance of Postgres.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, updated again.

Comment: Did you run `dotnet dev-certs https —trust` as suggested in the log?

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler no, I read that you're only supposed to do that in a dev environment, and not in a production environment.

Comment: How did you configure HTTPS? Did you use the `UseHttps(string fileName)` method overload to specify a certificate? More details can be found here (section "endpoint configuration): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#how-to-use-kestrel-in-aspnet-core-apps

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that Kestrel should be dealing with certificates. If I plan on having Nginx as a proxy in front of the asp.net core app (as is recommended), then I shouldn't have to worry about certificates on kestrel's side of things.

Comment: TBH, I would prefer the `nginx` approach as well.